# Hibernate mapping strategy for this type of scenario?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am very confused and not able to find out any solution for this scenario.

There is a Bank, and it needs to record all activities of its Account holders and its Employees like Teller.

There can be many activities:

1. Deposit Activity: It will point to account holder who deposited the money and teller who received the cash.
2. Similarly Withdrawal Activity.
3. Shopping Activity: If account holder does any shopping by his bank card.
4. Teller activity when he log in and log out of his cash counter.

and so many activities, that can be related:

- Only to account holder.
- Or only to teller.
- Or to both like deposit and withdrawal.

Now, how do I map all these activities, so they extend same super class "Activity"?

And, Can there be only single member in `AccountHolder` class, `List<Activity> activities` instead of different references for different activities.

Like `List<DepositActivity>`, `List<ShoppingActivity>`...

So, I can get all activities at once?

Tell me, If I haven't made my question clear enough to understand?

Comment: Why do these activities need to be separate classes? Bank transactions usually consist of an amount, source and target accounts, and metadata such as timestamp and description.

Comment: But why not? This scenario is the small part of my real scenario, which is so vast, so I have to use inheritance for scaling my application further. In my real scenario all these activities "Deposit Activity", "Shopping Activity" will contains so many attributes and will map to other tables also. So, I think, they need to be separate classes by using inheritance.

Comment: Do you need to be able to query across "all activities", or are queries limited to a particular activity type?

Comment: Actually, I need to show all Account Holder activities in a JList, order by activity time. So, yes, I need to be able to query across "all activities". That is why, I asked my second question, "to have reference to List<Activity> in AccountHolder class", so that I can get all account holder activities without writing a criteria or hql, if it is possible!